# User redirect to destination URL after login

Tags: redirect, urls, content-restriction

Scenario: if user not login, user redirect to customize login page and redirect again to destination page after login. I don't use a function or plugin.
This code to restriction page:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()){ wp_redirect( get_option('home') . '?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );
}
```

successfully to user login but in login page the URL change to ?page=login
and can't get URL redirect to destination page. How to make it? Anyone could help, please?

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar recently.

**1.** If the user is not logged in I captured the desired/destination page's URL and added it as a query arg to the login page's URL.

**2.** Redirect the user to the login page.

```
function wpa_59205_redirect(){
    global $post;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // this will tack on the current page's url as a query arg for the login page's url
        $redirect = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', get_permalink( $post->ID ), $url_of_your_login_page_here );
                // redirect to the login page
        wp_redirect( $redirect );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpa_59205_redirect' );
```

**3.** Then you can filter the URL that the user is redirected to after login, using the `login_redirect` filter.  Simply check for the presence of your previously added query var:

```
function wpa_59205_login_redirect( $redirect_to ){
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        return $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpa_59205_login_redirect');
```

I did this with a WooCommerce login page, so I was filtering their proprietary login redirect filter, but `login_redirect` is the WP default version of the same so I *think* it should work, but haven't tested it.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet should work fine.

First off, your custom login form may not respect `redirect_to`.  `wp-login.php` does, but you'll have to send the `redirect_to` argument to the `wp-login.php` form submission as well. Show the code for your login form.

You need to be careful how you use `wp_redirect`. It works by sending headers:

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirects to another page.
 *
 * @since 1.5.1
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'wp_redirect' hook on $location and $status.
 *
 * @param string $location The path to redirect to
 * @param int $status Status code to use
 * @return bool False if $location is not set
 */
function wp_redirect($location, $status = 302) {
    global $is_IIS;

    $location = apply_filters('wp_redirect', $location, $status);
    $status = apply_filters('wp_redirect_status', $status, $location);

    if ( !$location ) // allows the wp_redirect filter to cancel a redirect
        return false;

    $location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location);

    if ( !$is_IIS && php_sapi_name() != 'cgi-fcgi' )
        status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

    header("Location: $location", true, $status);
}
```

So if parts of your pages have already loaded and you're not using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php), it won't work.  `Headers already sent` and all that business.

If that's the case you might be better off just showing a message with a link to the login form or show the form itself (eg. [`wp_login_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)).

Second, you should always call `exit` or `die` after using `wp_redirect` this causes the execution of the PHP script (eg. WordPress) to finish, send headers and bail.  Otherwise things further down the page may kill your redirection headers.

```
<?php
wp_redirect(site_url('wp-login.php'));
exit;
```

Finally, if you are going to include the host in your `redirect_to` URL you should include the protocol.

You can also just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
<?php
$url = add_query_arg('redirect_to', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], site_url('wp-login.php'));
wp_redirect($url);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please note: wp_redirect will not be called if the page has started,
>   so make sure to call it higher up.

```
<?php 

    if (!is_user_logged_in()){
        $current_url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $current_url ) ); 
        exit;
    }
?>
```

wp_redirect: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

wp_login_url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

Comment: "wp_redirect will not be called if the page has started". Doesn't seem like that's true. There are no checks in `wp_redirect` to see if output has started, etc.