# wp-login.php -- redirect logged in users to custom URL

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

When a user login, we can easily change the redirect URL (see [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59205/user-redirect-to-destination-url-after-login), [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169704/redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in), or [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82047/send-users-logging-in-from-wp-login-php-directly-to-home-page-of-site-rather-th/82048#82048)), but if the user goes to `/wp-login.php`, they will be redirected to the dashboard **if they are already logged in**.

My question is, when the user visits `/wp-login.php` **and** is already logged in, how can I redirect them to a custom URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to figure out what's happening for a problem like this is to go to the source. Literally.

Take a look in [`wp-login.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2.2/wp-login.php) and look for an action that fires before any HTML rendering happens. The hook you're looking for is [`login_init`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2.2/wp-login.php#L447). Add a callback to it, check if the user is logged in and redirect them if so.

The only other snag here is that `wp-login.php` also handles logging out. So you need to check the [global `$action`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2.2/wp-login.php#L413) variable to make sure a logout isn't in progress.

```
add_action('login_init', 'wpse187831_redir_loggedin');
function wpse187831_redir_loggedin()
{
    global $action;

    if ('logout' === $action || !is_user_logged_in()) {
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect(apply_filters(
        'wpse187831_loggedin_redirect',
        current_user_can('read') ? admin_url() : home_url(),
        wp_get_current_user()
    ), 302);
    exit;
}
```

There's a bit of extra stuff there:

- A call to `apply_filters` so other plugins can hook in and modify my redirect if they like. This filter gets the redirect itself as well as the current user.
- There's a check to see if the current user can actually access the admin area before redirecting them there.

Here's that little snippet [as a plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/redir-logged-in-users.php).

Comment: Ah unfortunately, it appears this solution is preventing logout. Try clicking on default logout link on admin-bar or one generated with wp_logout_url() -- any way to escape if user is trying to logout?

Comment: Answer and plugin updated!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the current page is login or not using `$pagenow` global variable and the `wp_redirect()` to custom URL within the condition `is_user_logged_in`

```
function redirect_logged_in_user() 
{
    if( is_user_logged_in ) {
      wp_redirect('http://customurl');
    }
}

global $pagenow;
if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php')     
redirect_logged_in_user();
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, thank you for the answer. Although, when considering performance, is there any way to achieve this by hooking into something that only runs when user visits the wp-login.php page?

Comment: I couldn't find any built in function for finding login page, hence I had to use a global variable. Let me know if that works.