# wp-login.php — redirect logged in users to custom URL

Tags: redirect, login, wp-redirect

When the user visits `/wp-login.php` and is already logged in, how can I redirect them to a custom URL? I found the same question asked and answered, only relating on who to redirect to the admin panel but I don't want to do that, I want to redirect to a specific URL.([wp-login.php -- redirect logged in users to custom URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187831/wp-login-php-redirect-logged-in-users-to-custom-url/187874#187874?newreg=071333e83ee0428aa02b259efc1ba934)).

I am specifically wanting to redirect them to `my_home_URL.com/my-account` How would I accomplish this? Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!

EDIT: I had little success but the below function when accessing `wp-login.php` it does successfully redirect to the URL I have set. However it does this redirect no matter if the user is logged in or not. How do I fix it so it successfully runs `is_user_logged_in()`?

```
function redirect_logged_in_user() 
{
    if( is_user_logged_in ) {
      wp_redirect('http://customurl');
    }
}

global $pagenow;
if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php')     
redirect_logged_in_user();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be just a typo. Try writing:

is_user_logged_in()

Looks like just forgot the **()**

**UPDATE:**

Because you don't want to redirect on every page load you have to hook your redirect. I here an example (taken and slightly edited from the docs):

```
<?php
function daro_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        // edit this part accordingly to your login needs:
        // maybe you can skip the else statement
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'daro_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Awesome thanks I got it all working. The only thing I now have occuring is that this is overriding admin users also being sent to that custom URL I have setup. Can I have it check the user's role and if they are and admin send them to the WP admin panel?

Comment: Yes you can check the users role. Just one example I found googling: https://kellenmace.com/get-current-users-role-in-wordpress/